# Scrapy Writing into individual multiple files for every sub-links of a online news article site

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I have been trying to scrape this site "https://bangla.bdnews24.com/". I am using Python3.

Here is my spider code so far,

```
import scrapy 
import hashlib

class PostsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "posts"
    start_urls = [
        'https://bangla.bdnews24.com/'
    ]
    direc = ''

    def parse(self, response):
        #get all the article links
        post_link_list = response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "article")]/@href').extract()

        #follow link one by one 
        for post in post_link_list:
            hashed_url = self.hashcodes(post).upper()
            self.direc = hashed_url + '.json'
            yield response.follow(post, callback=self.parse_post)

    def parse_post(self, response):
        items = {}
        items['title'] = response.css('#news-details-page .print-only::text').get(),
        items['date'] = response.css('#article_notations span:nth-child(2)::text').get(),
        items['content'] = response.css('#storyBody p::text , .article_lead_text .print-only::text').extract()
        with open(self.direc, 'w', encoding="utf-8") as f:
            f.write(str(items))
        yield items

    def hashcodes(self, url):
        hc = hashlib.md5(url.encode())
        return hc.hexdigest()
```

what i am doing is collecting all the urls from the main page first then following them one by one and scraping data from those, parsing them. Also encoding the links **I want to put the individual link-scraped data into individual json files; using the encoded links as local directory names.** But the problem I am facing is, only one json file gets created and all the scraped data from all the links goes into that one file where one link's scraped data get overwritten by the immediate ones. So I am left with one json file where only the last link - scraped data is stored.

I would appreciate any advise on how I could update my code to do so. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would add another field to my item which states which link the item is from. I would then write a quick script to post process the data. If you need it all to work automagically you should implement a runner with a signal and collect all items and then sort using the items link field I suggested. This is how I would handle it. For simplicity just sort at the end, but if it needs to be in production and re-ran then you will need to consult the docs about using a runner and signals for items scraped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue. The problem being parse_post() was not getting the current page url or the variable "self.direc". I removed the self.direc variable and added this line inside parse_post() -

```
hashed_url = self.hashcodes(response.request.url).upper()
```

Here is the final code -

```
class PostsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "posts"
    start_urls = [
        'https://bangla.bdnews24.com/'
    ]


    def parse(self, response):
        #get all the article links
        post_link_list = response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "article")]/@href').extract()

        #follow link one by one 
        for post in post_link_list:
            yield scrapy.Request(post, callback=self.parse_post)


    def parse_post(self, response):
        items = {}
        items['title'] = response.css('#news-details-page .print-only::text').get(),
        items['date'] = response.css('#article_notations span:nth-child(2)::text').get(),
        items['content'] = response.css('#storyBody p::text , .article_lead_text .print-only::text').extract()

        #get the current page url and encode it 
        hashed_url = self.hashcodes(response.request.url).upper()
        direc = hashed_url + '.json'

        #write single page scraped data onto individual files
        with open(direc, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            json.dump(items, f, ensure_ascii=False)

        yield items


    def hashcodes(self, url):
        hc = hashlib.md5(url.encode())
        return hc.hexdigest()
```